# Hibernate Instantiation Failure On Serverside

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I'm using a mysql database with hibernate that works perfectly locally. 
But when I deploy it on my server I get the following stacktrace. 
Please help:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:110)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:433)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:231)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1313)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
>           at com.miiatech.tautona.red.patternindexer.util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:12)
>           ... 42 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:107)
>           ... 52 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
>           at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
>           at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:188)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:128)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:78)

Answer (score 2):

> "Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter".

It seems that you have problems with class path of your deployed application.